# "[INFO]" 10:55:55 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.8 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.5.4)

Tags: typescript, npm, version

I need to downgrade the version of typescript in that log.
I tried `npm uninstall typescript` and `npm install typescript@4.2.4` still the log in that line shows typescript version 4.5.4, I want it to be 4.2.4

Answer (score 1):

update to latest version

```
npm install -g ts-node@latest
npm install ts-node-dev@latest
```